# JOOQ - Update Statement with Expression

Tags: postgresql, jooq

In PostgreSQL you can use an expression which is able to make use of the column values for the given row to define the value in the set statement i.e

```
UPDATE some_table
SET col_a = (col_b != 1)
WHERE col_c = 'some val'
```

Is there a way to do this in JOOQ? - I've looked through the JOOQ documentation, but I can't see any reference to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming `col_a` is a `Field<Boolean>`, in case of which, you can wrap a `Condition` in a `Field<Boolean>` expression using [`DSL.field(Condition)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field(org.jooq.Condition))

```java
// As always, assuming you have this static import:
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;

ctx.update(SOME_TABLE)
   .set(SOME_TABLE.COL_A, field(SOME_TABLE.COL_B.ne(1)))
   .where(SOME_TABLE.COL_C.eq("some val"))
   .execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Following https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.13/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/update-statement/#N6ABB6, I think you would do

```
update(SOME_TABLE)
.set(row(SOME_TABLE.A),
     row(SOME_TABLE.B.neg()))
.where(SOME_TABLE.C.eq("some val"));
```

Comment: I did spot this, but I couldn't get it to work. The problem is the second row shouldn't use negate it needs to be equal to some parameter (like the where clause). But eq returns a Condition not a Field, which the row() needs. Any ideas?